# Appending a 0 in front of a variable in Python

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a variable called fab, and a Django queryset. As follows,

```
fab = self.request.GET.get('fab')
```

and my queryset,

```
queryset_df = Table1.objects.filter(Q(fab=int(fab)) | Q(fab=int(0+fab))).values_list('masks').distinct()
```

As seen I want to append a zero in front of the fab in my Q, because sometimes the fab comes as a integer value and sometimes with a 0 infront. When I tried to add by `+`, it returned me an error like, `unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'unicode'`. Any idea why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a string: → `'0' + ...`

Comment: What *field* type is `fab`? If it isn't an IntegerField, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cast the 0 to unicode or string before concatenating.

```
fab = "0" + fab
```

You can not concatenate a unicode variable with an integer, you can also not concatenate strings with integers or floats, so you need to convert one to the correct type.

Comment: No problem, if it helped you, you can mark it as answer so other people know the solution.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your logic is wrong somewhere,

You are either trying to force an integer into a `CharField` or you are trying to force a string into an `IntegerField`. If its the former you're always going to struggle with having to cast values to get the correct results and if its the latter the leading 0 is pointless.

You should try to use the correct field type, it will even help with your model's validation.